# onclick event not working in PHP page

Tags: javascript, php

I have a PHP page and I want to take an existing variable on the page and pass the data from it to a new window.

Here is the link code:

```
<?php
echo "<br /><span class=\"formlabel\"><em><a href='#' onclick='openPage(\"$gui_txt\");'>Guidelines</a></em> text for reference (not for editing):</span><br />\n";
?>
```

Here is the JavaScript function openPage:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function openPage(value){
    window.open('guidelinestexttest.php?value='+value);
  }
</script>
```

Nothing happens when I click the link, it just appends an # at the end of the URL in the address bar and does nothing.

Comment: Can you paste the output html generated by your php string?

Comment: Any errors in the Javascript console? What's the value of `$gui_txt`?

Comment: @user3620761 What? Where is the html?

Comment: $gui_txt is some rows from a database table, like basic text

Comment: javascript console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: @user3620761 Maybe your php string is being generated with some sintax error. Paste it here.

Comment: What do you mean paste a php string? $gui_txt returns data from a database table as text

Comment: try changing your onclick function call to this  - onclick='openPage('".$gui_txt."');'

Comment: If you are getting the "Unexpected token ILLEGAL" error, it is usually because there is a hidden character in your JavaScript code. Did you copy/paste it from something like Microsoft Word or JSFiddle? If so, you probably copied some unicode without realizing it. Open the HTML file in something like Notepad and you'll see a ? where the unicode character is hiding. Delete it and resave the file. Note: ANY error will stop your function from working.

Comment: akr - changing the onclick function outputs the $gui_txt value right onto the page...still not working

Answer (score 3):

To prevent the link from triggering, you have to either cancel the event, or return false, otherwise the page will reload because the event will continue to process `href='#'` for the current page.  Try `onclick='return openPage(\"$gui_txt\");'`, then return `false` from your function.  You can also pass in the event, and call '[*event*.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)'.

Comment: James Wilkins: here is what I have now (just testing):

function openPage(value){
window.open('guidelinestexttest.php?value='+value);
return false;
}

echo"<a href='#' onclick='return openPage(\"$gui_txt\");'>Hello</a>";

This, however, still only adds the # to the end of the URL and does not open a new page with the variable data

Comment: Then your script is not executing.

Comment: I updated the function and added return false; and then changed the onclick to the one you specified, was there something else?

Comment: Check for errors in the console (usually just press F12 on most browsers). It might help to view the page source and show what your final output is.

Comment: What I am trying to do is take the string data returned from $gui_txt and display it in a new window. So on the current page, the $gui_txt variable already has text assigned to it, I want to create a link to click and it will open a new window displaying that data from $gui_txt

Comment: Read my post above yours again.  Did you do this?  In your browser, right click to view the page source to confirm it got to your browser correctly.  If the source is not too big, perhaps even update your question with the example of what ACTUALLY makes it to your page (NOT just the PHP script only).  There might be other things going on that prevents your script from running (which is why I said to check the console for errors).